# How to find the timing information in a QR code?

Tags: graphics, qr-code, image-recognition

Suppose I have a QR code, how would I look for the timing information (and therefore determining the version and size of the code)?

When I detect a code, I look for the three dark squares, the alignment information. I can then morph the picture, so that the picture is upright, with all edges and modules the same size and in the correct orientation. The next step is to look for timing information, so I can start decoding the code. But how do I find it? I don't know how many modules there are in one line at that point, and therefore, I don't know the exact location. How would I detect the timing lines?

Please note, that I can't use a library to decode the picture information. The idea is to recognize the picture information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you could estimate the module size.

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) estimates it based on the 1-1-3-1-1 ring pattern of the finders.

There's actually a set timing pattern between the finders, if you know their positions fairly accurately. It's just a matter of walking the pixels and calculating the average length of the white and black regions.

The ZXing estimate is a bit cruder but works pretty well. There are cases where it produces an incorrect estimate that walking the timer pattern would probably eliminate. But the common use case for ZXing is a live stream of images and one incorrect estimate isn't a big deal.

Comment: Well, I was talking about the timing pattern between the alignment patter (the three large dots). Problem is, once I found the alignment pattern, how do I find that pattern? Should I just inspect the ring size of the alignment rings?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd do. Make some initial estimates based on the finder pattern and then confirm it/refine it via the timing marks. In theory, you can do something more signal-processing-like trying to find the highest frequency, i.e., smallest possible module size, but that gets kinda complicated relatively quickly and it's not clear that simpler heuristics don't work adequately.